# Running an ObjC++ program built with gcc without showing a terminal window

Tags: macos, gcc, objective-c++

I've put together a small C++/Objective-C++ app that runs in Windows with no problem.  When I build on a Mac, using gcc, it does work, but it always shows the Terminal while running.  In Windows, using MinGW I just add `-mwindows`. Any chance OS X has an equivalent?

Comment: Could you show us the errors that you are getting?

Comment: I didn't say anything about an error.  I'm just trying to figure out how to build something using gcc, and not have the Terminal come up when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

So I found my own answer- I put the app in a 'bundle' and got the results I wanted.  Created a folder and called it 'whatever.app', put a folder in it called MacOS, then dropped the output from gcc in there.  The root of the bundle folder also has to have an info.plist file with an entry "Executable file" that points to your executable.  Done, no more terminal when you run it.  There's probably a more proper way to do it (other than using XCode), but that's how I'm doing it for now.